# Копирование массива

Tags: c, массивы

Я пытаюсь прочитать символы из консоли, при этом я не знаю сколько символов я получу. Поэтому я объявляю динамический массив символов и читаю ввод посимвольно. Когда кол-во введенных символов достигает границы массива, я создаю новый массив, копирую в него символы из основного массива, снова объявляю массив с размером вдвое больше и копирую все в него.

```
void init(void){
// получаем строку цифр разделенных пробелами
    char part;
    int pos = 0;
    int len = 2;
    char* array = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    while (1){
        part = (char)getchar();
        if (part == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        array[pos] = part;
        pos++;
        if (pos == len) {
            char* buf = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
            for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
                buf[i] = array[i];
            }

            int old_len = len;
            len = len * 2;
            free(array);
            char* array = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
            for (int i = 0; i < old_len; ++i){
                array[i] = buf[i];
            }
            free(buf);
        }
    }
    printf("%lu", sizeof(array));
    printf("%s", array);
    free(array);
// генерируем на основе этой строки массив
// вычисляем сумму четных элементов
// выводим результат

}
```

Вопросов несколько. Почему `printf("%lu", sizeof(array));` всегда выводит 8? И почему когда кол-во символов достигает 16, то новое копирование не срабатывает, т.е. в `buf` уже ничего не копируется? При этом если я укажу `len` равным 32, а введенное кол-во символов будет соразмерно, то все хорошо, а если будет хоть на символ больше, то я получу мусор.

Comment: А что по-вашему должно выводить `printf("%lu", sizeof(array));`?

Comment: Потому что `array` у вас - указатель на `char`, а в 64-разрядном приложении размер указателя - 8 байт. Послушайте, а зачем это двойное копирование? Сначала в такой же буфер, потом назад...? Почему не срезу в новый буфер? И кто будет дописывать в конце нулевой символ, чтоб мусор не выводился?

Comment: я ожидал что `printf("%lu", sizeof(array));` выведет размер массива. а что такое 8 я не знаю.

Comment: `Послушайте, а зачем это двойное копирование? Сначала в такой же буфер, потом назад...? Почему не срезу в новый буфер?`
я не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать.
`И кто будет дописывать в конце нулевой символ, чтоб мусор не выводился?`
не знал что это требуется. попробую.

Comment: откуда такие ожидания? `array` же у вас не является массивом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему printf("%lu", sizeof(array)); всегда выводит 8?

Потому что `array` у вас - указатель на `char`, а в 64-разрядном приложении размер указателя - 8 байт.

С остальным... Держите код и сами разберитесь, в чем он отличается от вашего.

```
void init(void)
{
    char part;
    int pos = 0;
    int len = 2;
    char* array = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    while (1){
        part = (char)getchar();
        if (part == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        array[pos++] = part;
        if (pos == len-1)
        {
            char* buf = (char*)malloc(2*len*sizeof(char));
            for (int i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
                buf[i] = array[i];
            len *= 2;
            free(array);
            array = buf;
        }
    }
    array[pos] = 0;
    printf("%s", array);
    free(array);
}
```

И еще - если уж С, то вот эти приведения - `(char*)malloc...` - не нужны. Видимо, вы просто дали файлу расширение .cpp, вот он и компилируется как С++.

Comment: `Видимо, вы просто дали файлу расширение .cpp, вот он и компилируется как С++.` нет, это не так. файл имеет расширение `.c`, а приведение типа для `malloc` я вычитал и позже еще в видео уроке увидел. обосновывается это тем что `malloc` возвращает `void*`

Comment: В **С** - подчеркиваю - в **С** - это приведение излишне. Будет работать и без него.

Comment: `array[pos++] = part;` кажется это сначала увеличит pos на 1, а потом будет использовано в качестве индекса? правильно я понимаю, что в таком случае первый элемент не будет заполнен?

Comment: Нет, сначала заполнит, а потом увеличит. Так, как описали вы, было бы, если бы я написал `array[++pos]=part`

Comment: Если вместо malloc использовать realloc, то самому копировать данные не надо

Comment: да, а еще оказывается есть memcpy

Comment: Есть много чего. Только вы не разобрались еще даже со своим вариантом, а так пришлось бы с новыми разбираться. Вам бы сильно помогло, если бы я то же самое сделал в 3 раза короче через, скажем, `fgets`?

Comment: нет, конечно.хотя мне все еще не понятно, почему мой вариант решения не работает. а еще меня поражает, что все работает и без условия `if (pos == len-1)`. когда я считал, что уже давно должен был выйти за границы массива и упасть.

Comment: Неопределенное поведение на то и неопределенное, что вы можете работать без сбоя - ну, пишете туда, куда нельзя, но это не обязательно убьет программу. Как аналогия - переходить на красный свет нельзя, может задавить машина. Но это не значит, что при первом же переходе дороги на красный это обязательно произойдет :)

Comment: у меня от этого мозг закипает) спасибо большое за объяснение.

Comment: Ну, лишь бы машина не сбила в реальности :) В программе, конечно, лучше чтоб сразу сбой виден был...